# How can I add a custom item to the nautilus context menu, but NOT in a sub-menu?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I am interested in adding a custom script to the Nautilus context menu.  I am aware of solutions such as the Scripts folder and the Nautilus Actions application.

I created a test action in Nautilus Actions, but it only appears under the "Nautilus-Actions actions" submenu.

[image]

I would like to be able to add an item to the root level of the context menu itself (at the same level as cut, copy, dropbox, compress...) and not in a submenu.

Is this possible with Nautilus Actions?

If it isn't, is there any other way? (If it involves coding or strange configuration changes, that's OK too)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with nautilus-actions. Launch `nautilus-actions-config-tool` and go to Edit > Preferences > uncheck "Create a root Nautilus Actions menu"  and bottom of the first tab. -- This affects all actions.

[image]

Also, in the left panel the entries (actions) can be grouped as sub-menus. Create your actions (New action'), then create a  'New menu' with right-click or under 'File' for each action category, and then drag&drop your actions of that category on it.

[image]

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to explain a bit more.  Nautilus 3.4.2 does not have a 'tools' drop down menu.

Comment: @fabricator4, I've made an edit.. I can't say it was the hardest question I've seen around here..

Comment: A bit late but it was this simple - Edit > Preferences > uncheck "Create a root Nautilus Actions menu"

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know that's not possible with Nautilus Actions. But you can write a Nautilus extension  that adds a menu item. For Python install the package `python-nautilus` and have a look at the examples in `/usr/share/doc/python-nautilus/examples/`

Comment: It is possible...