# Running the java compiler with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, java, gnome-terminal

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to launch the java compiler in the folder that's opened in Nautilus.

I tried commands like these:

```
gnome-terminal -e #script that invokes the javac and adds stuff the the classpath#
```

But whatever I do, the terminal will start in my home folder, not in the folder I'm currently working in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to create a context menu entry similar to "Open in Terminal..." for directories in nautilus.
I do not know how to map nautilus menu entries to a key (You can activate the entry with multiple keys using the context menu by keyboard, like with <kbd>Menu</kbd>).
But as you seem to already solved the key mapping part, maybe some hints on how to configure a menu entry for the script help:

For starting [`gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) with a specific start directory for the shell, there is an option `--working-directory`:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory /some/java/dir -e startscript.sh
```

There is a `nautilus` extension to add menu entries: "Nautilus Actions". That would allow to implement the context menu that supplies the directory to use from nautilus.

It is described in one of the answers of [How do I customize the context menu in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus).
(See also [How can I add a custom item to the nautilus context menu, but NOT in a sub-menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215370/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-the-nautilus-context-menu-but-not-in-a-sub-menu))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that wont solve it because the working directory is unknown to the keyboard shortcut command. I cannot set the working dir to one final dir because I use multiple folders with source files in it. What I meant was going to a folder and pressing a keyboard shortcut to launch the javac there.

Comment: I see. I added some more hints - but still not a full solution. If it does not work with your keyboard shortcut, pleas describe how you configured that shortcut (In nautilus?).

Answer (score 0):

So this is sort of variation of my answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/602234/295286). Make sure you set the profile in your terminal to [hold the window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4468488/3701431) , then create the script bellow, and assign a keyboard shortcut to this script (basicall full path to the script as command of the shortcut).

When you are in nautilus folder where you wanna run java compiler, run

```
#!/bin/sh
# set -x
OPENDIR=$(zenity --entry --text="Type or paste address");gnome-terminal --working-directory=$OPENDIR -x javac *.java &
```