# Is it possible to open a terminal in the current directory?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am new to Ubuntu, and was wondering whether it is posible to open a terminal with a path matching your current location in the file manager? In Windows it was very easy, but how do you do it in Linux?

Comment: Upvoted and favorited, I'm very interested as well. It would be VERY convenient.

Comment: @kos found the related answer to the question, and linked it in my answer. I'd say this question is a duplicate

Comment: @Serg If you flag it so I can see the link, I'll flag it as well. Can't wait to see the answer either!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add “Open terminal here” to Nautilus' context menu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/207442/295286)

Comment: By the way, i added the plug in just now, works in 14.04 flawlessly

Comment: Why do we have a bounty on the question ? It's pretty much solved

Comment: @Serg I put the bounty because I'd like to make sure that there's no "native" workaround, or at least one that doesn't require an internet connection, which I cannot always afford while operating from a Live DVD. That would be really too useful to me, and I'll be happy to waste the bounty to make sure that there's no such thing.

Comment: @kos Would you consider a keyboard shortcut to very simple script to be a "native " workaround ?

Comment: @kos added the script+shortcut workaround, take a look

Comment: @Serg For some reason I didn't get the notifications for your comments. Anyway yes, I like it *way* more than downloading `nautilus-open-terminal`. Unless someone comes up with something better, which I believe it's hard at this point, I'll award the bounty to your answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From https://askubuntu.com/a/207448/371765

Run `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal` in a terminal, followed by `nautilus -q` to quit all open nautilus windows. When nautilus is next opened, a line saying `open in terminal` should appear in the right click menu.

Please note that the package `nautilus-open-terminal` is in the universe repositories.

Comment: This should be the correct answer: simple, direct, solves the problem and the program/plugin is already available in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I recall installing a gnome scripts package some time ago that added this functionality along with others like some "convert to ..." and etc. It was quite the learning experience and it led me to write a script to convert a directory of videos to .webm format (to conserve space). I beleive I found the package of which I speak at http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/

Comment: package "nautilus-open-terminal" (doesn't exist anymore with that name at least).

Comment: Since Ubuntu 15, including now 22.04, just right-click inside Folder and contextual Menu will show __Open in Terminal__

Answer (score 11):

**Update , April 11**

Create a simple script `opendirectory.sh` with the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh
# set -x
OPENDIR=$(zenity --entry --text="Type or paste address");gnome-terminal --working-directory="$OPENDIR" &
```

Bind that script to a shortcut , for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
+<kbd>i</kbd>, or whatever you like.

Now, when you are in some directory in nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open address bar. Copy the address of your current directory with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Lauch the shortcut you just created and paste the address with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in to the dialog. Terminal should pop-up with the directory that you told the dialog to open.

IMHO, this is as "native" as it gets and doesn't require additional installation. Sure, it is not a right click type of thing, but it works and can be implemented quickly. Will work for other file managers that don't support this option,too

**Original Post**

Technically nautilus, the default file manager, doesnt have `open terminal here` option, but [there is a plug in](https://askubuntu.com/a/207448/295286) for that in the repositories. You might be more interested in other file managers that support this option out of the box

As a workaround you could try the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> willopen the text filed for entering address, with the current working directory highlighted. Cut that out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, and paste into terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> or right click. Alternative , use run dialog to launch `gnome-terminal --working-directory=` and paste whatever you copied after = sign.

Drag and drop: Drag the button/tab (not sure how it's called) into terminal, add cd in front

[image]

Another way: Open the file manager and terminal. Drag and drop the folder  you want to access into terminal, and add `cd` to the path.

For instance, if I want to access `bin` directory in my `/home/serg/` directory, i would drag that directory to terminal and it would appear as `'/home/serg/bin'`. Next, add `cd`, so that the whole line is `cd '/home/serg/bin'` .

Comment: Can you tell me which file manager does that?

Comment: To be honest, this, IMO, is rather a workaround. I'm not even sure if it's actually more convenient than typing `cd <path>`.

Comment: Nemo, gnome-commander, I think thunar does as well, but dont quote me on that one

Comment: @kos well, it's the best that can be done with nautilus without the plugin, so . . .

Comment: Not to criticize, don't get me wrong, and I'm not even saying there's a better way. Maybe the right answer it's just "You can't, unless you change your file manager".

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have stated that in the first line.

Comment: `--working-directory=$OPENDIR` <- Will that still work if the directory contains spaces and special characters?

Comment: @gertvdijk Sorry for late response. The easy fix to that is to add double quotes around `$OPENDIR` , which I already added to my answer. And yes, it works, i tested that

Comment: Why not simply define `OPENDIR=$(echo $PWD)` instead of having to type /copy the directory name in the `zenity` dialogue?

Answer (score 11):

With [**Dolphin** [image: Install dolphin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dolphin), KDE's file manager, you have two options:

1. Open a terminal as a panel in the same window. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>F4</kbd> or the menu: *Control* → *Panels* → *Terminal*.

   The working directory is synchronized between the two panels; changing directories in either of the two panels will also change it in the other. Sweet!

   [image]

   In this screenshot you even see the sweetness of having this as a toolbar item in the top.
2. Open a terminal in a new window. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to do that. It will not have the feature to have the working directory synchronized, but it just opens a new window with the current working directory set.

The same applies to other apps in KDE Plasma, like the Kate text editor (enable it in Kate's settings, it's a built-in plug-in). Opening a terminal with a single keyboard shortcut from your text editor with the context of the file, is simply brilliant.

Comment: What does "connect the current directory" mean? (Sorry, I am not very knowledgeable about KDE 4.)

Comment: @EliahKagan I was referring to the feature of the first option in which the terminal follows path changes in the panel above and vice versa. The 'cd' commands seen in my screen shot aren't typed by me, but performed by browsing in the file manager.

Comment: "synchronized" would be a better word here

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, indeed. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small overview about the three file managers I know:

The file manager **Nemo** (part of the Cinnamon DE) has a built-in context menu option to both "Open as root" and "Open in a terminal".

The file manager **Thunar** (part of the Xubuntu/XFCE DE) even provides a feature to simply create user defined tasks that appear in the context menu. As an example, there is "Open a terminal here" included. I added an "Open as root" for directories myself. You can specify the command to execute, which parameters to give it and on which kinds of files/directories to show it.
<sub>I can expand my answer and add a more detailed explanation on how to create a custom context menu entry in Thunar. Please leave me a comment if anybody is interested.</sub>

The file manager **Nautilus** (part of the Unity DE, default for normal Ubuntu) provides neither of the two features built in nor the possibility to create custom context menu entries. However, there exists an additionally installable package to extend Nautilus' capabilities to open a folder in a terminal (see the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/602242/367990) of @ethanbmnz).

<sub>PS: I know that "Open as root" was not a feature requested by the OP, but I think it's related and not less useful than "Open in a terminal".</sub>

Answer (score 5):

No extra installation required simply right click inside the directory and take

> open in terminal

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

comes within nautilus in 15.04 by default.

Comment: For real ? Wow, finally !

Answer (score 3):

The `nautilus-open-terminal` package doesn't seem to be available for recent versions of Ubuntu, as noted in the [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu) linked in the accepted answer.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206655/587260) to that same question works for me in Ubuntu 20.04. Install `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal` by running

```
sudo apt install nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

and then quit Nautilus with

```
nautilus -q
```

and restart by opening any folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean opening a new terminal in a new window, with the same location as the previously opened terminal.

Then,
`Ctrl+Shift+N` does the work for me.

I am on Ubuntu 17.04.

Thank you.

Comment: it also work on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+N` is used to create a new folder. Atleast on Ubunutu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I understand that an answer is already provided and accepted, but I stumbled across this from my **Ubuntu MATE** configuration using the **`caja`** file manager, and naturally, couldn't readily apply any of these solutions.
So for those of you who may be looking for a way to do this in `Caja` on the `MATE Desktop`, here's something that may work (it worked for me):

Fire up `dconf-editor` from your start menu (or alternatively, from the terminal). Navigate to `org.mate.interface` and observe a checkbox with description "Can Change Accels". Mark that box as `true`.

Now fire up `caja` your favorite way. Go to the alt-menu at the top, look under "Files", and spot the option "Open in terminal" as always. Except this time, gently move your mouse (or keyboard scope) over to that option, and press a button combination (I like to use `Ctrl-Alt-H` meaning "open terminal HERE"). Now you should see that button combination on the drop-down menu, and should be able to use it. Note that you shouldn't set it to an existing combo such as the default `Ctrl-Alt-T` to open a terminal at your `~` directory. This method will not override existing combos.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-terminal --working-directory="$(xclip -o)"
```

I assign one shortkey to this script (in my case, <kbd>F4</kbd>).

When I am in a directory in my file manager, I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to highlight the directory path, and after that I press <kbd>F4</kbd> (the key I chose above to open the terminal). This is a another way of using the PC without taking the hands off your keyboard.

Instead of xfce4-terminal, you can use gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily open terminal for current file path by **right clicking** on the folder. At the right click menu there will be an option for **Open in Terminal**. This option will open the terminal for the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20 just install `nautilus-actions`.

Answer (score -2):

It is a really simple matter to deal with. You can simply install nautilus open terminal package and if you install it , then you can simply open terminal from any folder/director you wish just by right clicking and clicking on `open terminal here`. 
**To install it** 
all you want to do is to install it by opening a terminal, hope you know how. 
Then type this command and press enter :

`sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`

After installing go to a folder and try it. Just open home folder and right click >> Then select Open `terminal here`

or you have another choices to install other file manager and in some of them there is the function to open terminal here on right click menu. Nemo has it. Good luck

Comment: Is what you're suggesting any different from [ethanbmnz's answer, posted two weeks ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/602242/22949)?

Comment: @EliahKagan Sorry, I didn't notice it was helpful. Thats why I posted it.

Comment: @NivedKannada try finding workarounds,  like in my answer.  There has to be some more ways