# Terminal doesn't go to /home/username/downloads

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

When I type `cd /home`,  terminal goes there but when I type `cd /home/myusername/downloads` (or any address) terminal doesn't go there. It says `no such file or directory`.

Can somebody tell me what causes this?

Comment: Can you give more information? Possibly some screenshots? If you just do cd /home/yourusername does it work?

Comment: Yes it works if I only type that.

Comment: if you type cd /home/yourusername and then press <tab> a couple of times,  it should show you your possible options

Comment: I've just tried it, it shows desktop or other options but when i type i still get same error

Comment: It goes with things like /.local or /.mozilla but it doesn't go with folders

Comment: Capitalization is important. `/home/username/downloads` shouldn't work (unless you created the directory). `/home/username/Downloads` should work (unless you deleted/renamed the directory)

Comment: Capitalization is important. `/home/username/downloads` shouldn't work (unless you created the directory). `/home/username/Downloads` should work (unless you deleted/renamed the directory). Also use `ls` to view the contents of the directory you're currently in (unless you do `ls /path/to/other/directory`).

Comment: There's a nice game by the MIT for UNIX shell practice: http://web.mit.edu/mprat/Public/web/Terminus/Web/main.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The core of this question:** Directory names are case sensitive. Type `cd /home/username/Downloads` instead of lowercase.

**Additional information**

**Finding out directory names:**
You can use `ls` to list files and directories in any directory , to see their names. For instance, on a fresh install,  you most likely would find the following directories

```
$ ls /home/newuser
Desktop/    Downloads/        Music/     Public/     Videos/
Documents/  examples.desktop  Pictures/  Templates/
```

See how they are all capitalized? This is not the case with most of system directories, such as `/etc` or `/bin`. Traditionally, Unix/Linux commands and directories are all lower-case, though it's not a rule set in stone.

And by the way, there is `dir`, same as in Windows' cmd, a command which performs the same action - listing files in your current working directory.

There is an alternative: many file managers support an **Open Terminal Here** or **Open in Terminal** option. Nautilus, the default file manager for Ubuntu, does not have this feature by default as of 14.04 LTS, however there is a plugin you can install to enable this feature or use some work arounds. [Refer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/602234/295286) and answers to it for more information on opening a terminal from the file manager.

**Navigating in Terminal**

In order to navigate around your home directory, there are two "shortcuts", one is `cd $HOME/Downloads` and second is `cd ~/Downloads`.

In  the first case, `$HOME` is an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). If you run `env | sort` or `set | sort` you will see a long list of values sorted alphabetically, among which you will see a line `HOME=/home/yourusername`. When you run `cd $HOME/Downloads` the shell automatically expands `$HOME` to mean `/home/yourusername` and adds it to whatever else comes after `$HOME`.

For the second case, `~` also automatically gets substituted with the path to your home directory. [There is a historical reason for this particular character to represent the home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34196/85039)

There are also  a few tricks with `cd` command to make navigation even easier. `cd -` works kind of like a <kbd>go back</kbd> button in a browser; if you are in one directory but want to return from where you came and do not want to type full path, just enter `cd -`. For instance, if I jumped from `/home/Serg` to `/etc`, I can go back to my home folder by using that `cd -` command.

`cd ..` will let you go up one directory. For example `cd ..` from `/home/Serg` will  bring me up to `/home`.

And what if you want to jump from anywhere back to your home directory ? Just run `cd` by itself.

Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> will give you some suggestions on where to navigate, kind of works like auto-completion.

Occasionally you may want to enter a hidden directory with your settings, which will be initialized with a single dot, e.g. `.config` in your home directory. You might want to list them with `ls -a`. Of course you will need to type it exactly as it is listed , `cd .config`

And what if a directory has space or special characters in it? Again, use <kbd>TAB</kbd> button, or type everything by yourself, prepending spaces with backslash, e.g. `cd Folder\ With\ Spaces\ In\ Name`

**Suggestion:** Invest in a book with basic information on linux or shell programming. In my case, I found very helpful [Ubuntu Linux Toolbox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118183525)  and [Unix Shells by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013147572X). The power of Linux lies exactly in command line.

And the most important tip - have fun with it all, love what you do!

Comment: or type: ~/Downloads

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to accept the answer. Chili, yup, that's simpler =) also $HOME/Downloads

Comment: I installed ubuntu couple of hours ago for the very first time, I'm new this terminal stuff and I got here when I try to install Nvidia driver. Btw how can I accept your answer?

Comment: Gray check mark next to up down arrows on the left. When I come back home, I am going to improve my answer here, so it should help you navigate terminal easier

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm re-installing it though, I think I deleted something about x server and couldn't log in anymore I tried everything I can but didn't help. Btw what is the simplest way to install a graphic card drive? From a .run file. Or is there .deb or .rpm driver file which provided by nvidia?

Comment: Personally, I have not much of idea bout `nvidia` or other graphics drivers. You can certainly post another question or look if somebody has already asked it here or elsewhere. Nvidia seems to use `.run` files, so you may need to call those from command line