# Lost "Open terminal here" on upgrade from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, dolphin

In Kubuntu 14.10, the option "Open terminal here" was available in Dolphin's Actions menu. When I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.04, this option disappeared. How can it be restored?

Comment: Maybe you could create a .desktop file for terminal. What terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: @EduardoCola I use Konsole.

Comment: Create a desktop file with exec=konsole.

Comment: See also my answer to a similar question: http://askubuntu.com/a/606981/88802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KF5 Service Menus**

This is partial copy from: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?25740-Service-Menus-with-Dolphin&p=367207&viewfull=1#post367207

The Kubuntu 15.04 is a hybrid system. There are KDE4 applications and there are new KF5 applications.The KDE4 parts are looking the service menus from:

~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/
and
/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/

The new KF5 service menus are at:

~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
and
/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/

To get the KF5 service menus to the KDE4 applications the KF5 service menu directory can be linked to the KDE4 directory.

[image]

..and there are the KF5 service menus with the Dolphin (KDE4).

[image]

More of the Dolphin: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67996-Bug-275405-Dolphin-ignores-file-association-for-scripts-but-executes-them

Comment: For anyone else reading this, after I added the links, I had to log out and back in for them to take effect (restarting Dolphin wasn't good enough).

Answer (score 1):

In my installation of Kubuntu 15.10 solution is bit different. Copy only service menus is not enought.

Desktop files are in the right place `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/` and `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`, but ingored.

The solution is to copy plugin .desktop file to the new place too: from `/usr/share/kde4/servicetypes/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop` to `/usr/share/kservicetypes5/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop`

Script to finally fix this:

```
# Copy Service Menus and symlink old and new place
cp -r ~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/* ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
rm -rf ~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus
ln -s ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus ~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus

# Copy main plugin file
sudo cp /usr/share/kde4/servicetypes/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop /usr/share/kservicetypes5/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same [problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/689777/464928) as Peter Petrovich on Kubuntu 15.10. I solved this one using a hard file system link without copying. Thus, you do not break backward compatibility:

```
sudo ln /usr/share/kde4/servicetypes/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop /usr/share/kservicetypes5/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop
```